# E: Unable to locate package libccd-dev

Tags: package-management, software-installation, locate

I tried to install the package `libccd-dev` without success:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libccd-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libccd-dev"
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before `apt-get install`?

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: `libccd` is only part of the official repositories since 15.04. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libccd.

Comment: Yes, I run sudo apt-get update before sudo apt-get install. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the solution to my problem. If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to install libccd-dev, you have to add the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libccd-debs/ppa
```

and then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libccd-dev
```

as explained here:

https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issues/79/ompl-on-ubuntu-1404.

My main motivation to install libccd-dv was because I wanted to install OMPL.